# Weird spacing when using tabular inside of center inside of tcolorbox env

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, parbox

Here's a minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{workinprogress}[1][]{
  parbox=false,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{workinprogress}[oversize]
  this is a line
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
      hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello & hello\\
      world & world & world & world & world & world & world & world & world\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  this is a line
\end{workinprogress}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following on my machine (disergard the color, I just use a dark mode viewer),

[image]

but this on David Carlisle's [texlive.net](https://texlive.net/run),

[image]

Why are they different?

If I remove the `parbox=false,` option then the result on David's site stays the same, and that on my machine matches it.

---

In the documentation of the package, `parbox=false` is said to be an experimental setting (the default is `true`), but this does not answer the question of why I see two different behaviors for the same code.

Comment: your title asks about tabularx which is not used in the example?

Comment: texlive.net is texlive2022 last updated a few weeks ago, what distribution are you using?

Comment: you get the spacing you show first with texlive 2021 and the one with more space in texlive 2022 so it's an updated tcolorbox and you should update your system

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, I forgot to update it according to what I eventually wrote in the body. Let me fix it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if `\texttt{\pdftexbanner}` is the way to answer your question, then the answer is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/ArchLinux) kpathsea version 6.3.4`.

Comment: oh so you have tl2022 you are just missing an update or two. my log shows `Package: tcolorbox 2022/06/24 version 5.1.1 text color boxes` I guess yours is older

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I though Arch was always fresher. Apparently that's not _always_ the case. By the way, in an attempt to update using `tlmgr`, I think I broke `postnotes`, which now gives me a lot of errors, ahahah. I guess I'll have to ask another question :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue is caused by not using a fully-updated version of TeXLive.

Comment: a linux packaged texlive can never be ahead of the upstream source installed from tug which is what i'm using